# storing data in an array in php with multiple submission and eco self

Tags: php, arrays, forms, submit, self

Trying to print data from multiple submission, I want the names and roll numbers to get printed/passed to another form. These data will generated from several submissions. In the following code, only the last submission data is getting printed. Where am I going wrong.

`

```
<?php
$name[] = $_POST['name'];
$rollno[] = $_POST['rollno'];
$arrlength=count($name);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo $name[$x]." - - - - - -".$rollno[$x] ;
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="textfield" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roll No.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rollno" id="textfield2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

`

Comment: Your code is confusing.  You are only adding one element to the array with `$name[] = $_POST['name'];` so how do you expect more than one to be output?

Comment: Yes, I am confused here too. what should be the right one ?

Comment: What you want is most likely `$name = $_POST['name']` then use the array input types in the HTML like `<input name="name[]">` or you can look at the answer provided below for a starting point.

Comment: What I want is after I hit the submit button, the data gets stored into an array, then it is being printed. Again the submit button gets pressed. The new data gets stored into the array, both the old data and new data gets printed and so on. I tried a revised code, nothing happening.<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
  if (is_array($values))
{
  foreach( $_POST['name'] as $v ) 
  {
    echo $v;
  }
}
?>

In the form used :
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="textfield" />

Comment: where is is_array($values) coming from?

Comment: sorry, it is $name. but only the last submission is stored.

Comment: Update your original post with your revised code so I can see it better.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out and posted it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your input types are not array type. Use LIKE THIS
 <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="textfield" />
 <input type="text" name="name[2]" id="textfield" />
 .
 .
 .
 <input type="text" name="name[n]" id="textfield" />

 IN PHP CODE
 foreach( $_POST['name'] as $v ) {
    echo $v;
  }
```

Comment: What I want is after I hit the submit button, the data gets stored into an array, then it is being printed. Again the submit button gets pressed. The new data gets stored into the array, both the old data and new data gets printed and so on. I tried your suggestion with name[n] and the php code, not working.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. here is the revised code.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
$arrlength=count($name);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo $name[$x]."--".$rollno[$x] ;
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php
    $arrlength1=count($name);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength1;$x++)
  {
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='$name[$x]' /> " ;
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='rollno[]' value='$rollno[$x]' /> " ;
   }
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" id="textfield" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roll No.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rollno[]" id="textfield2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```